# Im trying to change the compiler for Solidity in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, solidity

I'm pretty new to coding so simple answers that are easy to understand would be greatly appreciated. I'm moving my code from Remix to VS code. I moved this contract from Remix:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

```
uint256 public favoriteNumber;

struct People {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    string name;
}

People[] public people;
mapping(string => uint256) public nameTofavoriteNumber;


function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}

function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
    return favoriteNumber;
}


function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber,_name ));
    nameTofavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
}
```

}

under my compile version I'm getting an error saying:

Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released versionsolc

to troubleshoot I've right clicked the error and clicked the Solidity:Change global compiler version(Remote) and clicked various different versions, only to see that my workspace seems to remain as 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang. Ive also went to  File>Preferences>Setting and went to Solidity: Compile Using Remote Version, and changed Solidity: Compile Using Local Version to v0.6.0+commit.26b70077 not really knowing what I was doing but taking information Ive got on the internet and STILL Im getting the same error.

Comment: i suspect that you are using a VSC Extension for Solidity, consult it's documentation regarding how to set the version to be used . if intended/obvious method doesn't work, search Issues/reports in the Extension's repository, and maybe create your own .

Comment: where do I find the documentation? And how would I create my own?

Comment: Find your Extension here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode , then read the readme and check it's "Repository" on the webpage if needed . To make an Extension you'll need JavaScript (at least for integration) , this https://code.visualstudio.com/api and probably VSC source code for info .